Best pattern for reuse in Vue 3 when components have the same props & logic, but very different HTML in their template
Occasionally I come across a case where multiple components have the same or near-identical props & script logic, but their display is so different that using conditional logic in the template doesn't really make sense.
For example, right now I have a case where I'm rendering metrics in different parts of an application with different visual appearance, but the processing logic in each of the components is pretty much identical.
What is the best pattern for code re-use here?

Pushing the logic into a composable?
Some kind of system for dynamic template selection?
Something else I haven't thought about?


Totally depends on a component. It could be a case for a common component that receives a template through a slot. "Pushing the logic into a composable" - yes. This limits you in a way props are defined because defineProps is a macro and cannot be extracted from a component

@EstusFlask - yeah, in this particular case I think I'd rather end up with a single component with a prop for which kind of display to use? So going into a composable seems like maybe not the right answer?

The component shouldn't be necessarily hardcoded to specific ones. It can be <CommonComp><template #default="slotProps"><AComp v-bind="slotProps"> All of these options are ok. It depends on the case, as said. SO isn't for reviewing workable code, but a specific implementation can be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

I discovered that we can use a SFC with only a template without props. Then we use its render function without prop type validation, the validation is done in a common component where we pass the common component's props to the render function. Looks cool at least at the first sight:
See on Vue SFC Playground
Template only SFC: Comp.vue
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>{{ title }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

Template only SFC: Comp1.vue
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

As you can see the props are identical but the templates are quite different.
Then our generic component with the magic of using the render function of our template only SFCs:
<script setup>
import { h } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  title: String,
  child: [Object, Function]
});
</script>
<template>
  <component :is="() => h(props.child.render, props)"/>
</template>

And usage:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Common from './Common.vue';
import Comp from './Comp.vue'
import Comp1 from './Comp1.vue'

const toggle = ref(true);
</script>

<template>
  <common :child="toggle ? Comp : Comp1" title="Title 1"/>
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</template>

